# iOS app rejected for VoIP background mode

Tags: ios, app-store, voip, background-mode

I have developed an application that uses Linphone VoIP API to receive incoming calls, but I don't want the user to make outgoing calls (because that's not what my app is supposed to do).
I have enabled VoIP background mode in my .plist but the app got rejected because "it would be appropriate to add a calling-out feature or remove the VoIP background mode". Now I don't want to add call-out features but I totally need VoIP background mode.

How am I supposed to make my app run in background waiting for incoming calls if not using VoIP background mode?

I need a strong answer from someone so that I can get the functionality to work fine and also be approved for the App Store.

Comment: I am using Twilio voice call and voip required but getting failed from app store.

Comment: @RahulMishra I am using the Twilio video calling for consultation with doctors. So is it possible for us to use the VoIP service with CallKit in order to show the Calling UI to patient when doctor initiates the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way out. I had to implement outgoing calls features.

Comment: That's exceedingly depressing.

Comment: I am already using Twilio voice call functionality but my app rejected from app store.