# iOS: Using CallKit & VoIP services for Video Conferencing with Doctors

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

I am working on an application which includes the video consultations between doctors and their patients. In the application, only doctors are allowed to initiate the call, not the patients. Patients can just accept an incoming call. Currently, I am trying to work on the CallKit for Calling UI with VoIP service and PushKit.

In some forums, I have read that the application needs to have both incoming and outgoing calls, but I am concerned as my doctor role in the application only provides outgoing call features and my patient role in the application only provide incoming call features. So will I be able to successfully upload it to the AppStore, or will the application be rejected?

I have already gone through this post, but I am not clear whether my use-case is same as the one mentioned in the post:

[iOS app rejected for VoIP background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155492/ios-app-rejected-for-voip-background-mode)

Answer (score -1):

just try to deselect the china form the country regions while uploading app to the play store. As some country regions does not allow VOIP functionality.

Comment: Pranav, have you got any previous experiences working on the VoIP notifications? I am asking just that I can get more details about whether apple will approve the application without incoming calling functionality for the doctor app and outgoing calling functionality for patient app. Can you please throw some light on that?\

Comment: I have recently uploaded my app with VOIP feature enabled in the app and they rejected my app saying that it can't be published in the china due to some reasons.Then i deselected china in my teretories while uploading on the app store or you can wrtie to them in the message where they show the reasons to reject the app.I just deselected the region and post the app then my app was launched succesfully;